# Subtracting Rows Based on status in another Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a ticket_id, status and time stamp for the that status change. In my calculation i need to remove any time the ticket was in monitoring state. So essentially i need to calculate the time when the ticket goes into monitoring and then comes out of. A ticket status can change multiple times. See the data in below (subtracting 13:40 from 13:46). I need to get the column 'Adjustment needed in mins'.

The expected result for this ticket example will be the column adjustment needed or a total of 5330 mins
Any help would be appreciated

| Entry ID | Time Stamp | Status | Adjustment needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 8/20/2021 13:46 | Changed to: Working | 6.3 |
| ABC | 8/20/2021 13:40 | Changed to: Monitoring | null |
| ABC | 8/20/2021 13:40 | Changed to: Working | 5324 |
| ABC | 8/16/2021 20:57 | Changed to: Monitoring | null |
| ABC | 8/16/2021 20:56 | Changed to: Working | null |
| ABC | 8/16/2021 12:40 | Changed to: Working | null |
| ABC | 8/16/2021 09:40 | Changed to: Working | null |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: *"See the data in attached image."* there is no image "attached", but don't embed an image either. If you want to supply sample data, do so as DDL and DML statements. Don't forget, as well, to include your attempts, and your expected results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just updated the post.

Comment: @Larnu Just updated the post

Comment: That's the sample data, @Datavizard , you're 1/3 there. Now we just need your expected results and attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can't have a ticket in the "monitoring" state twice in a row in date order, here's one solution of many. If the final state of the ticket in the data is still "monitoring" this solution will assume you want to subtract all the minutes up until now as well.

```sql
-- demo schema and data
create table tickets(id int, state varchar(16), changed_at datetime);

insert tickets 
values (1, 'state 1',      dateadd(minute, -7,  getdate())), 
       (1, 'monitoring',   dateadd(minute, -6,  getdate())), 
       (1, 'state 1',      dateadd(minute, -5,  getdate())),
       (1, 'state 2',      dateadd(minute, -4,  getdate())),
       (1, 'monitoring',   dateadd(minute, -3,  getdate())),
       (1, 'state 3',      dateadd(minute, -1,  getdate())),
       (2, 'state 1',      dateadd(minute, -10, getdate())),
       (2, 'monitoring',   dateadd(minute, -5,  getdate())); -- ticket 2's final state is still "monitoring"

select      id,
            duration_monitoring = sum(datediff(minute, t.changed_at, v.changed_at))
from        tickets  t
cross apply (
               select   top 1 changed_at
               from     tickets u
               where    u.id = t.id
               and      u.state != 'monitoring'
               and      u.changed_at > t.changed_at
               order by changed_at asc
            ) v
where       state = 'monitoring'
group by    id;

-- if you actually store to the second and want to round up...
select      id,
            duration_monitoring = ceiling(sum(datediff(second, t.changed_at, v.changed_at)) / 60.0)
from        tickets  t
cross apply (
               select   top 1 changed_at
               from     tickets u
               where    u.id = t.id
               and      u.state != 'monitoring'
               and      u.changed_at > t.changed_at
               order by changed_at asc
            ) v
where       state = 'monitoring'
group by    id;
```

Comment: Thank YOU. I dont think this is going to work given the last state of the ticket is resolved and we dont want to subtract time unitll now as well? Did you look at sample data in the post. The total minutes i want to subtract is 5330. Thanks again and appreciate the response.

Comment: The part that leaves subtracts the time until now if the final state is "monitoring" is the `outer apply`. You can just change that to `cross apply`, which will mean that time won't be subtracted from a ticket being monitored unless it has changed to something else.

Comment: @Datavizard I'm also not sure how you're getting "6.3" as the required adjustment for your top row, given that your storing the data to the precision of minutes. So my answer gives 5329, not 5330. If you are actually storing data to the second, then change the datediff to use seconds rather than minute and divide by 60 and round up.